# How to open custom object in salesforce UI?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created the below custom object, now I need to add the data to it.

[image]

I clicked on the edit button in the below screenshot.

[image]

then I clicked on the "Add More items"

[image]

But I don't see Author object under all items. Is it possible to explain why it is missing? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tab for your object (setup->tabs). It'll ask you to which apps it should be added (sales, service, marketing... The things you switch by clicking 3x3 grid icon in upper left corner) and who should be able to see the tab.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am able to see the custom objects now.

Comment: Somehow my created custom objects did NOT show up for me to select and create a new tab...